# how to connect silverlight with sqlite without IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, sqlite, local-storage

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

isf.DeleteFile("mydb.db");

using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "Version=3,uri=file:mydb.db";
    conn.Open();

    using (SqliteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {


        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE test_table ( [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [col] INTEGER UNIQUE, [col2] INTEGER, [col3] REAL, [col4] TEXT, [col5] BLOB)";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test_table(col, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES(@col, @col2, @col3, @col4, @col5);SELECT last_insert_rowid();";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@col", null);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@col2", null);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@col3", null);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@col4", null);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@col5", null);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        this.lstResult.Items.Add("Inserting 100 Rows with transaction");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@col"].Value = i;
            cmd.Parameters["@col2"].Value = i;
            cmd.Parameters["@col3"].Value = i * 0.515;
            cmd.Parameters["@col4"].Value = "hello world" + i;
            cmd.Parameters["@col5"].Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");

            object s = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        cmd.Transaction.Commit();
        cmd.Transaction = null;
        this.lstResult.Items.Add("Time taken :" + DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds + " ms.");

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test_table";
        using (SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var bytes = (byte[])reader.GetValue(5);
                this.lstResult.Items.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}, {5}",
                    reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetInt32(1),
                    reader.GetInt32(2),
                    reader.GetDouble(3),
                    reader.GetString(4),
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)));
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

This code works good, but is there anyway to connect to a database on my `D:` drive

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Version=3,uri=file:d:\mydb.db";
```

Or any other way to connect to any type of databases without using `IsolatedStorageFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the database on the server or the users computer?

If it is on the server, you will want to create a WCF service that accesses the database, then have Silverlight interact with the WCF service.

If it is on the users computer, you cannot access the local file system directly.  You will need to present the user with an `OpenFileDialog`.  The user will select the file, which will be made available as a `FileStream` on the `OpenFileDialog`.

If this is a Silverlight OOB app, things change a little bit.  You have more access to the user's system, but I'm not familiar enough with Silverlight OOB to make any recommendations.